# Keep Keep up until user scroll up

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have an issue with the `div` tag because my `div` is 300px high and there I need to keep scrolling down unless user scrolls up but, there is constant things coming in. To add on I do not want any jQuery, just pure javascript. How do I do this?

I have tried the css `flex-direction: column-reverse;` but it only works at the start when there is overflow. By:
 
HTML:

```
<div id="data"></div>
```

css:

```
#data{
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

javascritpt:

```
let AddData = setInterval(function () {
  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML+="More data";
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `flex-direction` property from CSS, as it does not work in this context as it is for a container element, and not a div element. Instead use the `scrollTop` property of the `div` element.

```
let dataDiv = document.getElementById('data');

let AddData = setInterval(function () {
  dataDiv.innerHTML += "More data<br>";
  dataDiv.scrollTop = dataDiv.scrollHeight;
}, 1000);
```

The line break `<br>` after the "More data" string is to make sure that each piece of data appears on a separate line.

Comment: To me the `.scrollHeight` does not work.